# Can I make Turkish Delight with jelly powder?

Tags: substitutions, candy, gelatin, middle-eastern-cuisine, turkish-cuisine

I have come across some Turkish Delight recipes [calling for cornstarch, others for gelatin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25413/turkish-delight-cornstarch-or-gelatine), some use both and one that uses store-bought [jelly powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin_dessert) (aka gelatin dessert aka Jell-O).

[The jelly powder recipe](http://www.cooks.com/recipe/iy0xg3d8/turkish-delight.html) confused me because it has few other ingredients, so how does it end up with the texture of Turkish Delight rather than gelatin dessert?

On the other hand, using store-bought powder gives me easy access to lots of flavours. Can I use store-bought jelly powder to make feels-like-the-real-thing Turkish Delight?

Comment: Can you expand on what differentiates this question from the linked one?  rumtscho's answer over there looks like it's also the answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer to the linked question states, original Turkish delight is made using only cornstarch. 
I understand you're asking specifically about the recipe linked and how it differs from other recipes. I'll try to answer the following points:

Q: **Why do some recipes call other gelling agents such as gelatin, next to cornstarch.**

*A: Like most thickeners, gelling agents, cornstarch is also susceptible to syneresis/weeping. Using other hydrocolloids helps preventing this. In Turkey, apart from traditional confectioneries, to cut down the syneresis, pectin is mainly used as the choice of additional gelling agent.*

Q: **Can gelatin alone be used to get the same texture, as the traditional Turkish Delight?**

*A: The answer is simply: "No". As gelatin will form a brittle gel, which is not really even close to texture of the gel that would be formed by gelatinized cornstarch.*